# Undergrad looking for study material/advice for applied mathematics.

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, education, learning

I am an undergraduate math student (junior) who is looking to get a masters degree in Applied Math. I like pure math, but I want to use my education to get a great-paying job. Here are a few questions that I have been dying to ask someone with experience:

1. From my understanding Applied Mathematics is highly dependent on computer programming and statistics, is that right? If so, I have zero background in programming. What should I do to kick start my programming abilities? Books, programs, hobbies, etc.
2. Is the job market good for applied mathematicians? Also, are the salaries good?
3. Do applied mathematicians work crazy hours? I've heard they do.
4. What potential careers do applied mathematicians have? And what is the most common? Are there any cool one's you've heard of?
5. What general advice do you have for and undergraduate mathematician seeking a degree and a career in applied mathematics?

Answer (score -1):

Are you really just asking for commonplace/cliché?

1. It is not true.
2. There are plenty of researches and rankings on this argument. But, are you really studying maths for salary or future job?
3. Does not make any sense
4. See 2.
5. Look at the arguments teached in your uni and see if you like it!

Remember, carrers are not based on what you have studied!

Many HRs does not even know what you have studied.
At junior level they are just looking for higly motivated, smart, fast learning (and son on) people.

However basic programming knowledge will help you.

Comment: I'd say that programming knowledge in languages like C++, python, and Matlab would help a whole lot for finding high paying jobs.